# How to start drill in distributed mode in window operating system

Tags: apache-drill

```
 I am using apache drill in window 10 having latest version (1.9).
```

`I want to start my drill in distributed mode.`
I have configure zookeeper `zoo.cfg` file:-

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=F:/zookeepertest/data
clientPort=2181
server.1=192.589.XX.01:2888:3888
server.1=192.565.XX.02:2888:3888
```

And Drill folder inside `drill-override.conf`

`drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "test",
  zk.connect: "192.589.XX.01:2181,192.565.XX.02:2181"
}`

**And my zookeeper is running..**

Now When i trying to start my drill using this command:-

`sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=192.589.XX.01:2181"`

Its thoughing following error:-

```
Error: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure setting up ZK for client. (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure setting up ZK for client.
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:161)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:70)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:143)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
        at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1083)
        at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1015)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:742)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:528)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:596)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: Failure setting up ZK for client.
        at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:245)
        at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:154)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failure to connect to the zookeeper cluster service within the allotted time of 10000 milliseconds.
        at org.apache.drill.exec.coord.zk.ZKClusterCoordinator.start(ZKClusterCoordinator.java:123)
        at org.apache.drill.exec.client.DrillClient.connect(DrillClient.java:243)
        ... 19 more
```

**Can anyone tell how to start drill in distributed mode in window.??**

Answer (score 0):

From [Drill documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-in-distributed-mode/)

To start drill in distributed mode, use `drillbit.sh` not `sqlline` i.e.

```
drillbit.sh start
```

Since `drillbit.sh` is a shell script (not a windows batch job) you'll need a 3rd party shell scripting tool such as [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or since you're using Windows 10, you can also enable [Bash on Ubuntu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).